# MySQL : Searching for Like '%%' query equivalent in full text search functions match() and against()

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to query longtext columns with **like'%term%'** but its taking too long. Mysql EXPLAIN is showing that no indexes are being used.

Full Text search functions match() and against() are not returning the desired results. I have tried +term, term*, "term", *term*,.. but not able to find the correct way to query so that **I get exactly the same result as with Like '%term%'.**

Full text search is giving me results in much less time but not as desired. How can I achieve this with full text search in mysql ? Or is there a way i can improve my like '%term%' searching ?

This is the sample data:

```
1   "ruleSetId"
2   [{"_ID":0,"Block":"ValidatorBlock","Key":"VALUE_VALIDATION_RULES","Description":"Validation Rule Failed.","DisplayName":"Value Validation Rule","Include":true,"Severity":"Alert","RowIndex":"0"}]
3   Value Validation Rule
4   "ExtractColumnName": "SP_RULE"
5   ", "BCC (L), LC", "ClosingRule", "Demo Portfolio
6   ", "BCC L, LC", "ClosingRule", "Demo Portfolio
7   ", "BCC L, LC", ClosingRule, "Demo Portfolio
8   ", "BCC L, LC", Closing Rule, "Demo Portfolio
9   [{"_ID":0,"Block":"ValidatorBlock","Key":"","Description":"Validation Rule Failed.","DisplayName":"Value Validation Rule","Include":true,"Severity":"Alert","RowIndex":"0"}]
10  [{"_ID":0,"Block":"ValidatorBlock","Key":"VALUE_VALIDATION_RULES","Description":"Validation Failed.","DisplayName":"Value Validation ","Include":true,"Severity":"Alert","RowIndex":"0"}]
11  "ruleSetId _"
12  "_ ruleSetId "
13  ruleSetId
14   : ruleSetId 
15  "ExtractColumnName": "SP$RULE"
16  "ExtractColumnName": "SPRULE"
17  "ExtractColumnName": "SPRULE"
```

Query1 : select * from testfulltext  where config like '%rule%'; Gives me all 17 rows which is the desired result.

Query2: select * from testfulltext  where match(config) against('+rule*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);  gives me 10 rows.

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: where is your tried query ..?